# Embeddings for negative Soboloev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

May one conclude from $u \in W^{-1,2}(\Omega)$ and $\phi \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ that also $u\phi \in W^{-1,2}(\Omega) $?

Intuitively this seems clear and I tried to do this in the same way as the usual $L^p$-estimates by pulling out the $L^\infty$-norm but my problem is that I can't apply this in the definition of the $W^{-1,2}$-norm. I also tried to estimate

$\| u\phi \|_{W^{-1,2}} \leq \| u\phi \|_{L^2} \leq \| \phi \|_{L^\infty}\| u \|_{L^2}$

but as far as I know we can't estimate $\|\cdot\|_{L^2} \leq \| \cdot \|_{W^{-1,2}}$. Is there maybe some other estimate like $\|\cdot\|_{L^p} \leq \| \cdot \|_{W^{-1,2}}$ for some $p<2$ I could use or another embedding theorem I don't know? Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Idea: try to work with the adjoint operator.

Comment: How do you define $u \phi \in W^{-1,2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Here, the space $W^{-1,2}$ is defined as dual space of $W_0^{1,2}$. I've also read definitions, where $W^{-1.2}$ is introduced as the space of functions, where the corresponding norm is finite, so in my question above I just assumed, if I can show one of the definitions, the other one follows immediately.

Comment: I guess the question can be interpreted as: does there exist a bounded bilinear operator $B:H^{-1} \times L^{\infty} \to H^{-1}$ which restricts to pointwise multiplication on smooth functions of compact support? Pretty sure the answer is false even in the simplest case $\Omega = \Bbb T$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this completely correct, but I think one can interpret the question like this, yes. Thank you.